# Convert numpy array from 2D to 3D

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I'm trying to input a 2D numpy array into a model based on a 3D dataset however I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected gru_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (37L, 2L)
```

So I expand the axis to try to solve the error however I get a new error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected gru_1_input to have shape (None, None, 1) but got array with shape (1L, 37L, 2L)
```

I'm not really sure how to solve the issue, and dont have the skills to re-adjust the model without probably breaking something. Here's the code so far to produce a prediction from the model:

```
#Load in Libraries
import keras.models
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##Input data
#a = np.random.random([1,24,1])

# Load CSV
filename = 'test1.csv'
raw_data = open(filename, 'rt')
b = np.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=",")
a = np.expand_dims(b, axis=0)


#Loads model and predicts forecast for future 12 points based on input data
MDL_NAME = "gru_relu"
model = keras.models.load_model("models/%s.mdl" % MDL_NAME)
pred = model.predict(a, batch_size=1, verbose=0)

#Plots the input data and forecast
plt.plot(pred[0], "b-o", label="Prediction")
plt.plot(a[0], "r-o", label="Past")

plt.show()
```

Comment: what command exactly causes the error?

Comment: pred = model.predict(a, batch_size=1, verbose=0) is mentioned in the callback, where check_batch_axis=False) comes before the ValueError

Comment: You need to tell us what shape of an array does your code (`model`) expect.  Evidently it expects 3d.  But is it right add a dimension at the start?; may be it should be at the end.  We, and you, need to know something about the model.

Comment: The 2nd error message suggests that `model` expects the last dimension to be size 1, not the first dimension.  Change the `expand_dims` call.  But as I wrote earlier, it would best if we read the documentation, and didn't just stumble around in the dark hoping to find a solution.

Comment: Prior to model building the training dataset is loaded and split into a 3D dataset. Here the code before model building (sorry if it isn't the correct information you requested):

# Split into 3D dataset
datasets = [(dataset[0][:,:,np.newaxis], dataset[1]) for dataset in datasets]
train_set, valid_set, test_set = datasets

Comment: The "L" letters appearing in the shapes in the error messages suggest something is definitely not right about your arrays (You probably have python lists as elements instead of having a numpy array with only numbers). Have you tried using a **tuple** instead of a list in `np.random.random((1,24,1))`?

Comment: np.random.random((1,24,1)) already works fine, I'm trying to focus on putting a csv file into the compatible type of array